# Profiling JOIN and Subquery Queries in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, subquery, left-join, profiling

**Problem Description**
I have an audit table that contains history changes of some objects. The audit contains a unique audit event id, id of the object being changed, date of the change, the property that has been changed and also before and after change values and other columns.

What I need to do is query the audit data and get the date the same field was previously changed on the same object. So I need to look at the audit a second time and for each audit entry add the previous similar entry with it's date as the previous change date.

**Schema & Data**
The table schema has id (id) as the primary key and the object id (parent_id) as an index. Nothing else is indexed. In my test case I have roughly 150 objects with around 80k audit entries for them.

**Solution**
There are two obvious solutions sub-queries and left join.

In left join I basically join the same audit table on itself again with the join statement making sure the object, field and value changes are correspond, the changes are older than the current change and select the max change date and finally to only pickup one latest previous change I group by id. In case no previous change has been found use the creation date of the object itself.
LEFT JOIN SQL

```
SELECT `audit`.`id` AS `id`,
`audit`.`parent_id` AS `parent_id`,
`audit`.`date_created` AS `date_created`,
COALESCE(MAX(`audit_prev`.`date_created`), `audit_parent`.`date_entered`) AS `date_created_before`,
`audit`.`field_name` AS `field_name`,
`audit`.`before_value_string` AS `before_value_string`,
`audit`.`after_value_string` AS `after_value_string`
FROM `opportunities_audit` `audit`
LEFT JOIN `opportunities_audit` `audit_prev`
    ON(`audit`.`parent_id` = `audit_prev`.`parent_id`
        AND `audit_prev`.`date_created` < `audit`.`date_created`
        AND `audit_prev`.`after_value_string` = `audit`.`before_value_string`
        AND `audit`.`field_name` = `audit_prev`.`field_name`)
LEFT JOIN `opportunities` `audit_parent` ON(`audit`.`parent_id` = `audit_parent`.`id`)
GROUP BY `audit`.`id`;
```

Subquery logic is rather similar but instead grouping and using the MAX function I simply have order by date DESC and LIMIT 1

```
SELECT `audit`.`id` AS `id`,
`audit`.`parent_id` AS `parent_id`,
`audit`.`date_created` AS `date_created`,
COALESCE((SELECT `audit_prev`.`date_created`
    FROM `opportunities_audit` AS `audit_prev`
    WHERE
        (`audit_prev`.`parent_id` = `audit`.`parent_id`)
        AND (`audit_prev`.`date_created` < `audit`.`date_created`)
        AND (`audit_prev`.`after_value_string` = `audit`.`before_value_string`)
        AND (`audit_prev`.`field_name` = `audit`.`field_name` )
        ORDER BY `date_created` DESC
    LIMIT 1
), `audit_parent`.`date_entered`) AS `date_created_before`,
`audit`.`field_name` AS `field_name`,
`audit`.`before_value_string` AS `before_value_string`,
`audit`.`after_value_string` AS `after_value_string`
FROM `opportunities_audit` `audit`
LEFT JOIN `opportunities` `audit_parent` ON(`audit`.`parent_id` = `audit_parent`.`id`);
```

Both queries produce identical result sets.

**Issue**
When I run the query in phpMyAdmin the solution with join takes roughly 2m30s to return the result. However, phpMyAdmin says the query took 0.04 seconds. When I run the subquery solution the result comes back immediately and the reported execution time by phpMyAdmin is something like 0.06 seconds.

So I have a hard time understanding where this difference in actual execution time comes from. My initial guess was that the problem would be related to phpMyAdmin's automatic LIMITS on the returned data set- while the result has 80k rows it only displays 25. But adding the LIMIT manually to the queries makes them both execute fast.

Also running the queries from the command line mysql tool returns the full result sets for both queries and the reported execution times correspond to the actual execution time and the method using joins is still roughly 1.5x faster then subquery.

From the profiler data it seems that the bulk of that wait time is spent on sending data. As it takes sending data takes in the order of minutes and everything else is in the order of microseconds.

**Still why would the behaviour of phpMyAdmin differ so greatly in the case of the two queries?**

Comment: It is because of PHPMyAdmin's overhead in fetching the datapacket, processing it (generating the views etc) and rendering it on your browser. Query execution was fast and results were generated immediately.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yea I can think phpMyAdmin does some sketchy stuff here but I can't wrap my head around why it would be only for one of the solutions when the output and number of rows is identical?

Comment: Well lot of things are involved, including network speed, type of data being rendered etc. I would not pay too much heed to it. You can use MySQL Workbench, if you are concerned about PHPMyAdmin's slowness.